# SFINAE, Invoking a functor if the operator is implemented

Tags: c++, c++17, sfinae

I have a `std::tuple` with a bunch of functors that implements callbacks with different arguments. I want to iterate over the tuple at compilation time and execute the functors compatibles with the arguments:

Let's say I have a set of functors:

```
struct functor_a { void operator()(const class_x&) {} };
struct functor_b { void operator()(const class_x&) {} void operator()(const class_y&) {} };
struct functor_c { void operator()(const class_x&) {} void operator()(const class_z&) {} };
```

Given a tuple containing them:

```
using tuple_type = std::tuple<functor_a, functor_b, functor_c>;
```

I want to do something like:

```
struct executor {

    template<typename message_type, typename... Type>
    static constexpr void exec(std::tuple<Types...>& tup, const message_type& msg) {
        exec(std::index_sequence_for<Types...>(), tup. msg);
    }

    template<typename message_type, std::size_t... Is>
    static void exec(std::index_sequence<Is...>, tuple_type& tup, const message_type& msg) {
        if constexpr (std::is_nothrow_invocable_v<typename std::tuple_element<Is, tuple_type>::type..., message_type>) {
            std::invoke(std::get<Is>(tup)..., msg);
        }
    }
}
};
```

In order to do this (or alternatively use std::invoke):

```
auto tup = get_tuple();
executor::exec(tup, class_x()); // Call functor a, b, c
executor::exec(tup, class_y()); // Call functor b
executor::exec(tup, class_z()); // Call functor c
```

I am having some problems with the constexpr condition that is always evaluated to true, and the code does not compile because it does not find the operator with the given argument:

```
std::is_nothrow_invocable_v<typename std::tuple_element<Is, tuple_type>::type..., message_type>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `std::apply`, some generic lambdas and [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) to make a single function

```
template <typename Tuple, typename... Args>
constexpr void dispatch(Tuple&& tup, Args const&... args) 
{
    constexpr auto dispatch_helper = [] (auto&& func, auto&&...args)
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<decltype(func), decltype(args)...>)
            std::invoke(std::forward<decltype(func)>(func), std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };

    std::apply([&](auto&&... funcs)
    {
        (dispatch_helper(std::forward<decltype(funcs)>(funcs), args...), ...);
    }, std::forward<Tuple>(tup));
}
```

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/-qFmEG) is a full example.

Comment: Clean & elegant! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Start with a single function object, conditionally invoked:

```
#define FWD(x) static_cast<decltype(x)&&>(x)

template <typename F, typename T>
void maybe_invoke(F&& f, T&& t) {
    if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<F, T>) {
        std::invoke(FWD(f), FWD(t));
    }
}
```

Now, we need a way to do something for every type in a tuple. We can do this with `std::apply` (to get all the innards of the `tuple`) and then folding over the comma operator (to call our function on each innard):

```
template <typename Tuple, typename F>
void for_each_tuple(Tuple&& tuple, F&& f) {
    std::apply([&](auto&&... args){
        (f(FWD(args)), ...);
    }, FWD(tuple));
}
```

Then, put those two together:

```
struct executor {
    template<typename message_type, typename... Type>
    static constexpr void exec(std::tuple<Types...>& tup, const message_type& msg) {
        for_each_tuple(tup, [&](auto&& f){
            maybe_invoke(FWD(f), msg);
        });
    }
};
```

---

You don't even really *need* `maybe_invoke` (but might be nice to have it as a separable piece anyway). This also works fine:

```
struct executor {
    template<typename message_type, typename... Type>
    static constexpr void exec(std::tuple<Types...>& tup, const message_type& msg) {
        for_each_tuple(tup, [&](auto& f){
            if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<decltype(f), decltype(msg)>) {
                std::invoke(f, msg);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Why are you using a `FWD()` macro defined as `static_cast`, instead of just using `std::forward()`?

Comment: @Remy Because `FWD(x)` is substantially shorter than `std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)` and why instantiate a template if you don't have to?

Answer (score 1):

I find it simply easier to employ garden-variety SFINAE, rather than a `constexpr if`, tested with gcc 9.2.1 in `-std=c++17` mode:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>

struct class_x {};
struct class_y {};
struct class_z {};

struct functor_a {
    void operator()(const class_x&)
    {
        std::cout << "functor_a: class_x" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct functor_b {
    void operator()(const class_x&)
    {
        std::cout << "functor_b: class_x" << std::endl;
    }

    void operator()(const class_y&)
    {
        std::cout << "functor_b: class_y" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct functor_c {
    void operator()(const class_x&)
    {
        std::cout << "functor_c: class_x" << std::endl;
    }

    void operator()(const class_y&)
    {
        std::cout << "functor_c: class_y" << std::endl;
    }

    void operator()(const class_z&)
    {
        std::cout << "functor_c: class_z" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct executor {

    template<typename message_type,
         typename tuple_type>
    static inline void exec(tuple_type &tuple,
                const message_type &message)
    {
        exec_impl(tuple, message,
              std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<tuple_type>>{});
    }

    template<typename message_type,
         typename tuple_type,
         std::size_t ...i>
    static void exec_impl(tuple_type &tuple,
                  const message_type &message,
                  std::index_sequence<i...>)
    {
        (exec_invoke_impl(std::get<i>(tuple), message), ...);
    }

    template<typename invocable, typename message_type,
         typename=void>
    struct invoke_impl {
        static inline void invoke(const invocable &i,
                      const message_type &m)
        {
        }
    };

    template<typename message_type, typename functor_type>
    static void exec_invoke_impl(functor_type &f,
                     const message_type &message)
    {
        invoke_impl<functor_type, message_type>::invoke(f, message);
    }
};

template<typename invocable, typename message_type>
struct executor::invoke_impl<
    invocable, message_type,
    std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<invocable &&>()
                 (std::declval<const message_type &>()))>>
{
    static inline void invoke(invocable &i,
                  const message_type &m)
    {
        i(m);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::tuple<functor_a, functor_b, functor_c> t;

    executor::exec(t, class_x{});
    executor::exec(t, class_y{});
    executor::exec(t, class_z{});

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
functor_a: class_x
functor_b: class_x
functor_c: class_x
functor_b: class_y
functor_c: class_y
functor_c: class_z
```